# Xamarin testing with TestComplete

Tags: android, xamarin, testcomplete

I've asked the same questions in the TestComplete forum already but I hope to find someone here who knows Xamarin well as most of my questions are more related to Xamarin than to TestComplete.

We are about to switch all of our apps to Xamarin and wish to continue UI Testing with TestComplete. Previously (when testing native Android apps), we used the object id to identify ui controls that was specified in the Android View xmls. This was very handy as the ids were

- human-readable
- unique
- constant across app runs

On Xamarin, controls seem to have ids, too, but we have some issues with them:

- Most objects have no id, some have an md5-hash as their id. It was so convenient on Android to have unique ids for most controls and this seems to be gone on Xamarin. Three questions concerning that: What are those md5-hashes based on, when do they change and is there any possibility to still set our own control id?
- Some objects appear twice with the same id but a different ObjectIndex. I know this phenomenon only from iOS, where the UI is created during runtime and sometimes UI controls don't get recycled properly so if you reopen the same view again, you might end up with to identical controls, one of them beeing invisible and the other one being visible. This is a pain in the bum on iOS since it can be quite hard sometimes to determine in TestComplete the instance that is currently visible. My hope is now that we can somehow get rid of that too, but I have no idea how.

[image: Screenshot of object ids: (1): md5-hashes, (2) Some objects appear twice]

Screenshot of object ids: (1): md5-hashes, (2) Some objects appear twice

- Objects are only accessible to a certain level. For instance, we can access and interact with `md52....MasterDetailContainer` but its only child `View("NO_ID")` is inaccessible. TestComplete cannot show a screenshot of it in the ObjectBrowser and any interaction with it (including "Highlight on screen") results in an error. This applies to all of its children, too. This is especially important to solve as all of our UI controls are children of that MasterDetailContainer and having no access to its children renders the tests useless.
- TestComplete, the Xamarin Forms Designer and the Android UI Automator Viewer show a very different object hierarchy of the same view in the app. How can this be explained?

I've been talking to the dev team about all this but as they are new to Xamarin, too, they don't know the answers neither. I would be glad if someone here who knows Xamarin coudl help us out as some of the issues are blocking issues.

Answer (score 0):

> set our own control id?

The control id that you are referring in that screenshot is showing that Java class name of the View. Xamarin creates Android Callable Wrappers(`ACW`) during that build process for each of the Java objects that you are creating/accessing from `C#`.

The default package names for ACW will be based on the **MD5SUM of the assembly-qualified name** of the type being exported.

You can control the generated name by using class attributes:

- `RegisterAttribute`
- `BroadcastReceiverAttribute`.`Name`
- `ContentProviderAttribute`.`Name`
- `ActivityAttribute`.`Name`
- `ServiceAttribute`.`Name`
- `ApplicationAttribute`.`Name`

i.e. If you had a subclassed `EditView` and want to override the default ACW name generation:

```
[Register("com.sushihangover.SOApplication.AVeryCustomEditView")]
public class CustomEditView : EditView
{
   ~~~
}
```

But, since you referenced `Xamarins.Forms`, I *assuming* you are not using AXML (`Xamarin.Android`) but XAML (`Xamarin.Forms`) to create your UIs. Forms programmatically creates the view hierarchy via unique platform-based renderers and its own layout manager and thus you will not have a one-to-one mapping of the XAML you are visualizing via Xamarin Forms Designer to what is created and viewed via the Android UI Automator Viewer nor will you have those view classes available to apply the `Register` attribute to.

Since SmartBear says they support `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android`, you should create a support case with SmartBear to understand how and if they also support `Xamarin.Forms` based UIs.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Unfortunately, we use Xamarin.Forms but I'll ask SmartBear about it.